# Discrete Math composition functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Give examples of sets $X$, $Y$, $Z$ and functions $f: X \to Y$, $g: Y \to Z$, so that
the composition $g\circ f: X \to Z$ is a bijection, although neither $f$ or $g$ it is.

I have no idea to begin thinking on amounts.

Comment: You could simply make $Y$ bigger than $X$ or $Z$. Let $f$ be a bijection from $X$ to some subset of $Y$, then define $g$ is a suitable way on that subset.  What $g$ does with the other members of $Y$ doesn't matter as long as they map to something in $Z$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=Z=\{1\}$ and $Y=\{1,2\}$.
Now take $f$ injective but not surjective: $f(1)=1$.
Moreover take $g$ surjective but not injective: $g(1)=g(2)=1$. 
Verify that $g\circ f:X\to Z$ is a bijecton.

Comment: Can i ask what f(1) and g(1) stands for Robert Z?

Comment: @Jonas Bo $f(a)=b$ means that the function $f$ send $a$ in $b$.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG we can take $Z = X$ and $g \circ f = Id$

If you can apply $f$ without "losing information", it's because $f$ is bijective on its image, i.e. injective.
Thus take Y bigger than X.
Then you just have to left invert $f$.

If you want to take $Z \neq X$ and $g \circ f \neq Id$, just left compose with a bijection from $X$ to $Z$.